# How to create a button that shows some li I have already hide them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.products-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.products-wrapper ul {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 30px;
    row-gap: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    list-style: none;
}
.products-wrapper ul li {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
}
.products-wrapper ul li:nth-of-type(1n+5)
{
    display: none;
}
.load-more-btn
{
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.load-more-btn button
{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="product-card">
                <a href="html/items/men/tops/m-tops-1.html">
                    <img class="image" src="products/men/tops/winter/m-top-1.jpg">
                </a>
                <div class="shopping-options">
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="name">balck leather jacket</h2>
                        <span class="price">egp 250</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="product-card">
                <a href="html/items/men/tops/m-tops-2.html">
                    <img class="image" src="products/men/tops/winter/m-top-2.jpg">
                </a>
                <div class="shopping-options">
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="name">silver leather jacket</h2>
                        <span class="price">egp 250</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="product-card">
                <a href="html/items/men/tops/m-tops-3.html">
                    <img class="image" src="products/men/tops/winter/m-top-3.jpg">
                </a>
                <div class="shopping-options">
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="name">grey leather jacket</h2>
                        <span class="price">egp 250</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="product-card">
                <a href="html/items/men/tops/m-tops-4.html">
                    <img class="image" src="products/men/tops/winter/m-top-4.jpg">
                </a>
                <div class="shopping-options">
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="name">dark green waterproof jacket</h2>
                        <span class="price">egp 250</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="product-card">
                <a href="html/items/men/tops/m-tops-5.html">
                    <img class="image" src="products/men/tops/winter/m-top-5.jpg">
                </a>
                <div class="shopping-options">
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="name">grey coat</h2>
                        <span class="price">egp 250</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="product-card">
                <a href="html/items/men/tops/m-tops-6.html">
                    <img class="image" src="products/men/tops/winter/m-top-6.jpg">
                </a>
                <div class="shopping-options">
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="name">grey sleeveless jacket</h2>
                        <span class="price">egp 250</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="load-more-btn"><button>load more</button></div>
</div>
```

how can I increase(1n+5) using a js function?

now there is 6 li every li is an item... I limited the shown items to 4 items only by styling the li with "nth-of-type(1n+5)", and I let other items display equals none so it.
now how can I use the "load more" button to increase the "5" of the nth so it shows more items when I click it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to write another query selector? If so, you just have to change the string you're providing to `querySelectorAll`. e.g. ```(a, b) => `.products-wrapper ul li:nth-of-type(${a}n+${b}`);```

Comment: I want to add button to show more items... So I limited the list items to 4 items using nth-of-type(n1+5)... Now I want to increase the 5 of the nth when I click the button.

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
const getNth = (num,offset) => `${num}n+${offset}`

listItems = document
  .querySelectorAll(`.products-wrapper ul li:nth-of-type(${getNth(1,5)})`)
```

Comment: I want to add button to show more items... So I limited the list items to 4 items using nth-of-type(n1+5)... Now I want to increase the 5 of the nth when I click the button.

Comment: Please add relevant HTML and button to your question. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor to provide a [mcve]

Comment: How can I send you an image?... because it says to many code and I have to add more text.

Comment: We need a [mcve], not your whole page. And if they want more text, explain in more details

Comment: Ok, I  add the snippet code.

Comment: You have no script in your post that shows where you want to increase the number in listItems

Comment: that's my problem. I don't know how to shows more items when I the click "more items" button... I just knew that in order to do what I need I should use the "nth" selector. if you can help me with any other method I'll be thankful, and I'm sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, however, try this if it helps

```
  let a = 1, b = 5
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll(`.products-wrapper ul li:nth-of-type(${a}n+${b})`)
```

Comment: I want to add button to show more items... So I limited the list items to 4 items using nth-of-type(n1+5)... Now I want to increase the 5 of the nth when I click the button.